# Django admin: inherit base class field such that it is used to set the model's field on save

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have model `Cake`. `BakedCake` has a foreign key to `Cake` and includes a `created_utc` field of type  datetime.

Say I have models `CupCake`, `LemonCake`, `CheeseCake`, each have a foreign key field `baked_cake` to model `BakedCake`, because they share this behaviour and a lot of other behaviour, they all inherit from the same base class `BaseModel`.

Now in the Django admin interfaces for `CupCake`, `LemonCake`, `CheeseCake`, we we wish to show a list of `Cake`s not `BakedCake`s, so the list is much shorter and easier to select from. Hence we rather show a list of `cake`s, then once the user has selected a `cake`, we use the current datetime and buisness logic to set the appropriate `baked_caked` on save.

Demo code:

```py
# --- models.py

class Cake(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Bar name", max_length=200, unique=True)

class BakedCake(models.Model):
    cake = models.ForeignKey(Cake, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    created_utc = models.DateTimeField()

class BaseModel(models.Model):
    baked_cake = models.ForeignKey(BakedCake, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    # -- Lots of other common business logic here --

class CupCake(BaseModel):
    custom_field = models.CharField("Example1", max_length=200, unique=True)

class LemonCake(BaseModel):
    other_field = models.BooleanField("Example2", default=True, )

class CheeseCake(BaseModel):
    another_field = SmallFloatField("Example3", )

# --- admin.py

class BaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)  # This form object does not have .fields attribute
        form.fields = [x for x in form.fields if x != 'baked_cake']
        form.fields += 'cake'
        return form

@admin.register(CupCake)
class CupCakeAdmin(BaseAdmin):
    pass

@admin.register(LemonCake)
class LemonCakeAdmin(BaseAdmin):
    pass

@admin.register(CheeseCake)
class CheeseCakeAdmin(BaseAdmin):
    pass
```

Unfortunately `form.fields` does not exist on the `form` object. How does one replace a field of a base `ModelAdmin` class such that its derived classes inherit these changes too?

### Summary

What I am trying to do is instead of showing the orginal model's field in the admin interface, show an alternate field of another model, then on save use the busines logic to select the appropiate original field. This needs to happen in multiple models, hence the inheriting the logic from a base model.

Note: Using Django 3

Comment: How is a field "difficult" to select?

Comment: I couldn't see any field named `bar` in your model definition. Did you miss that? @run_the_race

Comment: @markwalker_ Difficult to select because of the business logic, which is time based, includeds long historic entries which are mostly not relevent, and using certain rules the list can be reduced from thousands to a select box of about 50.

Comment: @JPG Sorry the question is a bit confusing, I edited it to make it more clear.

Comment: You could technically customize the form yourself - see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form, which also mentions you can get the default form and then customize it. I have not tried it myself (so not posting this as an answer), but this may set you in the right direction. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setup of model admin class definitely works (at least in Django 3.1)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms
from .models import Cake


class AbstractModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_baked_cake_instance(self, cake):
        return "something"

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, change=False, **kwargs):
        form = forms.modelform_factory(self.model, exclude=("baked_cake",))
        form.base_fields["cake"] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Cake.objects.all())
        return form

    def save_form(self, request, form, change):
        model_instance = form.save(commit=False)
        model_instance.baked_cake = self.get_baked_cake_instance(form.cleaned_data["cake"])
        return model_instance
```

and then, register your models,

```
admin.site.register(CupCake, AbstractModelAdmin)
admin.site.register(LemonCake, AbstractModelAdmin)
admin.site.register(CheeseCake, AbstractModelAdmin)
```

**Example Screenshot**

[image: Example Screenshot]

**Note**: Don't forget to complete the **`get_baked_cake_instance(...)`** method with your logic !!!

Comment: Thank you so much worked perfectly! How did you know about `form.base_fields` ?